# Creating a dedicated HD parition at beginning of disk for data files, benefits and draw backs?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, hardware

I am thinking of creating a dedicated partition on the harddisk for the mysql database data files in /var/lib/mysql , while considering those 2 points:

1. a dedicated partition will avoid any file fragmentation that might occur, even if fragmentation occurred it would be very limited.
2. benefit from the faster throughput and lower latency at the beginning of the mechanical harddisk.

What are the (other) benefits and possible drawbacks of such system ?

Edit:

More details about my situation:

I have 1 harddisk, actually it is 2 harddisks but in RAID1

It will contain: the database, the webserver, the os and other services.

Os will be Debian 6/7. Filesystem will be EXT3/EXT4

Comment: on the same disk as the OS or seperate Disk? What is the OS and what disk format you use?

Comment: @RaymondN question answered as an edit to the question.